# Error on storing date value into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I had try several type of date format and yet, I stil can't get it right.

Below are the coding which had been writen

```
Dim serverDate As String = Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")
strNew &= "INSERT INTO Staff ("
            strNew &= "full_name"
            strNew &= ", login_id"
            strNew &= ", passwd"
            strNew &= ", last_update"
            strNew &= ") VALUES ("
            strNew &= "'" & txt_Name.Text & "'"
            strNew &= ", '" & txt_Login.Text & "'"
            strNew &= ", '" & txt_Password.Text & "'"
            strNew &= ", (STR_TO_DATE('" & serverDate & "', '%d-%m-%Y'))"
            strNew &= ")"
```

Any idea what had I missed out?.. Helps are much appreciated..

Edit #1:
Forgot to add in the error message
"Incorrect datetime value :'DD-09-YYYY' for function str_to_date"

Comment: Why my question had been voted down?.. TT_____TT
I am really out of idea how to solve the question then only i post it in here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **hard-coded** sql string so you need to use yyyy-MM-dd format date.

```
Dim serverDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

strNew &= "INSERT INTO Staff ("
            strNew &= "full_name"
            strNew &= ", login_id"
            strNew &= ", passwd"
            strNew &= ", last_update"
            strNew &= ") VALUES ("
            strNew &= "'" & txt_Name.Text & "'"
            strNew &= ", '" & txt_Login.Text & "'"
            strNew &= ", '" & txt_Password.Text & "'"
            strNew &= ", '" & serverDate & "'"
            strNew &= ")
```

EDIT:

> @BlurrieBlue :
>   Forgot to add in the error message "Incorrect datetime value
>   :'DD-09-YYYY' for function str_to_date"

Yes it is incorrect format. It should be

```
Format(Now(), "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Take a look at this code-snippet

```
cmd=new MySqlCommand()
cmd.Connection=cn
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO Staff (?full_name,?login_id,?passwd,?last_update)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("?full_name", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txt_Name.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("?login_id", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txt_Login.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("?passwd", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =txt_Password.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("?last_update", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value =DateTime.Now

cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

Off-topic: Don't use [hard-coded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) sql string. Use parameterized sql statement.

Comment: I tried to use stored procedure to get the serverTime before but it had problem storing in the database too..

Comment: I had try the solution given but it still give me the same error message.. Do i need to import any library in?

Comment: @BlurrieBlue : Which provide API you are using (.net connection?)

Comment: Thx for the help!!~.. the format had been change and the data can be saved now ^^